# Is it okay to handle all the $http errors in controller?

Tags: angularjs

In all my services, I'm just invoking `REST services` and returning the `promises` to the controllers. All the error's are handled at controllers using `catch` like below,

```
MyService.getData(url).then(getDataSuccess).catch(exception.catcher('Contact Admin : '));
```

My question here is, Since the real `$http` calls will be made at service, should I have to write catchers in service or catching in controller is fine?,

```
Scenario 1: 
     function getData(url){
             return $http.get(url);
     }

Scenario 2: (Nested calls to make combined results)
     function getOtherData(url){

         var defer = $q.defer();

         $http.get(url).then(
            function(response){
                $http.get(nextService).then(
                    function(res){
                         defer.resolve('combined data');
                    }
                )                      
            }
         );

         return defer.promise;
     }
```

Both the service method is not handling any errors. Instead it just returns the promise. Will there be any situation where this kind of exception handling will get failed?

<sub>Note: I have created decorators for handling javascript,angular errors and route errors separately. This question is particularly about $http service errors.</sub>

Comment: I think in controller you should all business login stuff.In your factory where you using services should  handled http error handling mechanism

Comment: I prefer to handle errors in my factories/services. [Here](https://toddmotto.com/rethinking-angular-js-controllers/)  is an interesting article on the topic, and in which I am basing my style.

Answer (score 1):

Yes what you have can fail triggering your `catch` because you have no `reject()`.

You are using an *anti-pattern* creating your own promise and not chaining the nested request properly. Neither of those request rejections will be returned anywhere.

To be able to chain these get rid of the `$q.defer()` and do:

```
function getOtherData(url) {

    // return beginning of promise chain
    return $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
        // return next promise
        return $http.get(nextService).then(function (res) {
            // combine and return the data 
            return {
                d1 : response.data,
                d2 : res.data
            };
        });
    });    
}
```

Now walk through the scenarios and each part of chain is intact.

Think of the chain as each `then`  needs a `return` until the end of the chain

Answer (score 1):

Scenario 2: (Nested calls to make combined results)

> Failed Scenario

```
 function getOtherData(url){

     var defer = $q.defer();

     $http.get(url).then(
        function(response){
            $http.get(nextService).then(
                function(res){
                     defer.resolve('combined data');
                }
            )                      
        }
     );

     return defer.promise;
 }
```

This scenario will fail if the first `$http.get` has an error. The promise will hang and never get resolved. This is why we recommend avoiding using `$q.defer` to create promises from services that already return promises.

Instead **return** data and **chain** promises.

```
function getOtherData(url) {
    var promise = $http.get(url);

    var derivedPromise =
        promise.then ( function (response) {
            var data = response.data;
            var nextPromise = $http.get(nextService);
            var derivedNext = nextPromise.then(function(response) {
                 //return for chaining
                 return response.data;
            });
            //return composite for chaining
            return $q.all([data, derivedNext]);
         });

    return derivedPromise;
};
```

The `getOtherData(url)` promise will be fulfilled with an array with the data from the two XHRs or it will be rejected with the first error response.

It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs.<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)</sup>

---

### Chaining error handlers

In an error handler, to **convert** a rejected resolution to a fulfilled resolution **return** data. To **chain** a rejection, **throw** the error.

For example:

```
 promise = http.get(someUrl);

 derivedPromise = promise.catch(function(errorResponse) { 
     if (fixable) {
         fixedPromise = $http.get(fixedUrl);
         //return to convert
         return fixedPromise;
     } else {
         //throw to chain rejection
         throw errorResponse;
     }
 };
```

By **chaining** error handlers, errors can be handled both by the service and the client of the service.

This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs like $http's response interceptors.<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)</sup>

Comment: A solution using `$q.all` might look better if you unnest the calls.

Comment: @Duncan My example returns a promise that resolves to [data1, data2]. I didn't want something unsymmetric like [data1, response2].

Comment: No, it wouldn't be asymmetric. Too long for a comment though so I added it as another answer.

Comment: Could you please add one more point about whether to write `catch` in controllers or service? If it has to be in service, then how promises should be resolved|rejected in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Building on @georgeawg's answer, if you want to return multiple sets of data then you don't need nested calls.

```
function getOtherData(url) {
    var promise1 = $http.get(url).then ( function (response) {
        return response.data;
    });
    var promise2 = $http.get(nextService).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    });

    return $q.all([promise1, promise2]);
};
```

Now the caller gets a promise that resolves to a list of the 2 data items (or is rejected if either request fails). The only real difference is that both requests are issues in parallel.

This generalises easily to a situation where you could have a list of urls, fetch them all in parallel and get an array of the response.data items.

Because you get back only a single promise that resolves to an array of data you can handle the result in the controller, but you only need one error handler.

```
MyService.getOtherData(url)
.then(getDataSuccess)
.catch(exception.catcher('Contact Admin : '));
```

Although the original question doesn't specify, it might be the case that the second url depends on the result from the first. You can handle that case here as well if you remember that you can call `.then()` multiple times on the same promise:

```
function getOtherData(url) {
    var promise1 = $http.get(url).then ( function (response) {
        return response.data;
    });
    var promise2 = promise1.then(function(response) {
        // compute nextService from response.data here...
        var nextService = foo(response.data); 
        return $http.get(nextService).then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    });

    return $q.all([promise1, promise2]);
};
```

Comment: That will work if the url for the nextService is known. If the nextService url is derived from data from the first XHR, then the promises need to be **chained**.

Comment: Updated my answer to cover that case as well.